# Failed to CoCreate Profiler error - but not using a profiler

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, profiler

We're getting a:

> .NET Runtime version 2.0.50727.5448 - Failed to CoCreate profiler

message in the Event Viewer on our webserver, along with an accompanying:

> .NET Runtime version 4.0.30319.239 - Loading profiler failed during CoCreateInstance.  Profiler CLSID: '{d37a1b78-6dc5-46fc-bc31-f7c4d5a11c9c}'.  HRESULT: 0x8007007e.  Process ID (decimal): 224.  Message ID: [0x2504].

The thing is, we're not trying to use a profiler, there are no profiler's running or installed on the server and the code makes no reference to profilers anywhere...

We've tried removing the registry keys that other's have pointed out are related to these messages but to no avail; it would seem that two of our websites/webapps are firing off the error, one using .Net2 and the other using 4, but I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: I have this problem now after uninstalling dotTrace. Was also getting errors when it was installed but not profiling which led me to uninstall it.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

After much searching I found that someone had previously installed dotTrace, then uninstalled it, however the uninstall wasn't very clean and had left the registry littered with entries, though we'd removed some entries we thought could stop the problem there were more specific to that profiler.

After removing all registry entries related to dottrace and the CSID it presented we no longer have the error appearing in the event viewer.

See this answer for a script to aid in hunting down such entries: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36129656/361842

Comment: Also had this problem with every profiler I have ever used.  Which is kind of ridiculous that a product created to find errors and issues, creates an issue on your pc upon being uninstalled.

Answer (score 20):

Removing Environment variable COR_ENABLE_PROFILING (or set it to 0) from User variables (Control panel > System > Advanced system settings > Environment variables) solved my problem (Could not start MongoVUE)

Comment: Important: it may happen that setting to 0 does not help, only removal helps

Comment: Thank you, I had a problem performing a SQL task and after a few days of following up your answer was excellent
Thank you very much again

Answer (score 16):

While removing all the references to the profiler's CLSID in the registry can't be a bad thing, you can also choose to just disable profiling by setting the registry key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\.NETFramework\COR_ENABLE_PROFILING` to `0`

Comment: I still get the error after setting COR_ENABLE_PROFILING to 0. Needs reboot?

Comment: @rushonerok I don't remember if a reboot is needed, but if you're on a 64 bit OS there's a second key to set: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\.NETFramework\COR_ENABLE_PROFILING`

Comment: thats probably it. Andreas answer also works but the registry entries should be changed too. thanks.

Answer (score 12):

To help find where this tool may be used, the below PowerShell code can be used to help detect environment variables and registry entries relating to the profiler:

```
clear-host
if (-not (get-psdrive HKU)) {
    New-PSDrive HKU Registry HKEY_USERS
    Set-Location HKU:
}
"COR_ENABLE_PROFILING: $env:COR_ENABLE_PROFILING "
"COR_PROFILER: $env:COR_PROFILER"
$GUID = $env:COR_PROFILER
@(
    "HKLM:\Software\Classes\CLSID\$GUID",
    "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Classes\Wow6432Node\CLSID\$GUID",
    "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Classes\CLSID\$GUID",
    "HKU:\*\Software\Classes\CLSID\$GUID"
) |
    get-item  | 
    %{$p = $_.Name;Get-ItemProperty $_.PSPath ''} | 
    select @{N='Path';E={$p}}, '(default)'

get-itemproperty 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\*\' 'Environment' -ea SilentlyContinue | 
    %{
        $serviceName = $_.PSChildName
        $x = new-object PSObject -Property @{ServiceName=$serviceName}
        $_ | select -expand Environment | 
            %{if($_ -match '^(?<Name>[^=]+)(=)?(?<Value>.*)$'){$x | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $matches['Name'] -Value $matches['Value']}}
        $x
    } |
    ?{$_.COR_ENABLE_PROFILING -eq 1} | 
    ft ServiceName, COR_ENABLE_PROFILING, COR_PROFILER, NEWRELIC_INSTALL_PATH -AutoSize
```

Hope that helps others in future.

Comment: Very useful script, thanks. In my case it seemed that Stackify Prefix was causing K2 Blackpearl's old v2 app pool to wig out and die. I uninstalled Prefix and the problem was resolved. Shame I didn't find this a couple of days ago and save myself some pain!

Answer (score 10):

[image: regedit]

1. Use *regedit* do a *Data* search for the CLSID value in the error log
2. Remove COR_PROFILER and its value
3. Change Cor_Enable_Profiling=1 to Cor_Enable_Profiling=0
4. Do **not** remove the Cor_Enable_Profiling setting for any of the following:

   ```
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Services\WAS
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\Services\W3SVC
    HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\services\IISADMI‌​N
   ```

   Doing so may cause IIS to fail to start. See [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/210903/windows-process-activation-service-wont-start-parameter-is-incorrect-visual/210912) for more details.
5. You may also need to remove/disable additional User and System variables. Try disabling first (COR_ENABLE_PROFILING = 0) delete if error persist. Hope that helps. Thank you @Andreas and @Mike-Monkey for the initial guidance.

[image: Environment Variables]

Comment: a note of interest, the profiler registered in your environment variables is Stackify's profiler.

Answer (score 1):

For us COR_ENABLE_PROFILING was at multiple places

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\\Services\W3SVC and HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\\Services\WAS

Answer (score 0):

Stackify Profiler Will also do the same thing to you. :(, I am finding it difficult to remove from the registry.

Comment: if its running, you can use the tray app to remove the profiler from the registry with the "Disable Profiler" option

Answer (score 0):

We see this problem from time to time when trying to start Windows Services.
This issue is invariably that the app.config for the executable is corrupt (not valid xml).
Double checking that your app.config is valid xml is a quick easy thing to check before heading of to edit registry settings..

Answer (score 0):

Things did not work even after doing what mentioned in [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22373643/740756) from Agnes. In my case, I had my application pool set to an account and it's password was expired...