Visual Studio runtime dependencies - unable to find
I installed VS 2015 on a Windows server. Created a C++ project which contains an .exe & .dll (com). The .dll is registered using regsvr32.
When I run the binary & .dll on another server where VS2015 is not installed, CoCreateInstance for the .dll fails & shows the following error:

.NET Runtime version 4.0.30319.34209 - Loading profiler failed during CoCreateInstance.  Profiler CLSID: ''.  HRESULT: 0x8007007f.  Process ID (decimal): 2344.  Message ID: [0x2504].

I installed runtime dependencies like VS 2013 / VS 2015 redistributed packages, .NET 4.5.1 & 4.6, but the issue is not resolved.
While debugging, I found msvcr120_clr0400.dll was absent. After installing the .NET framework, the .dll is copied, but the issue isn't resolved.
Can someone suggest which runtime package is missing?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10013493/failed-to-cocreate-profiler-error-but-not-using-a-profiler
